# Can not copy in Google Docs using Safari

Tags: safari, copy-paste, google, google-docs

I've had this problem for a little while now (can't recall what would have triggered it). I'm using Safari 6.0.5 on 10.8.4 on an early 2011 15" MBP.

When I try to copy anything using the keyboard from google docs nothing happens - I also hear an audible error noise. I think it's Safari saying "HAHA - sucker". Anyhow, I can paste into GDocs with whatever is in the clipboard at the time. I also use PopClip, which gives you the option to copy text when something is selected - that works as normal. If I try to copy something from the edit menu, I get the "These actions are unavailable via the Edit menu, but you can still use:" error dialog.

Cleared cash, disabled plugins, restarted computer...etc...none of the typical troubleshooting stuff works.

Ideas?

Comment: Could it be the keyboard shortcut for Safari not working?

Comment: I just tested this. Using ⌘ + C, the first time it doesn't make a noise, and it copies the source text correctly. However, if I press ⌘ + C again without first moving the cursor, I get the "beep" error noise. Is it possible you're accidentally hitting it twice?

Comment: @buscar - I don't think so because it works on other sites.
@ KevinSchumacher - I does it on the first one for me. Good to know it at least does it on the second for you. I'll try some more troubleshooting and report back.

Comment: Just to clarify! how do you try to access "your" Google documents from Safari?

Comment: I just made a google doc (spreadsheet), than made it public, that used Safari to access it, then tried copy cmd-c, all works. Note, I also allowed others to edit it!

Comment: Funny enough - it turned out to be PopClip causing the problem. After quitting it I was able to copy as expect in Google Docs. I've email the developer to see if he knows of any fix.

Comment: It looks like you have an answer - PopClip was causing your difficulties. Feel free to let us know if you wish to have this reopened so you can answer it or clarify what problem you are seeking to solve at this point.

Comment: Please reopen this, this is valid problem with Safari and Google Docs, not related to PopClip.

Comment: @SorinSbarnea Since the original question was resolved by pointing to PopClip as the source of the issue, please feel free to ask a new question with information specific to your problem.

Answer (score -1):

I have recently switched from Chrome to Safari and now I'm having this problem when working in Google Docs.  I'm sorry to say I don't have a solution at this time.

Comment: You've posted this as an answer, which is only for things that directly answer the question asked. If you have a different question, feel free to ask it using the Ask Question button at the top right.

Comment: Deep in the comments was an answer - PopClip can cause Google Docs to not work on Safari - so that might help you if you don't want to re-ask this.